# Unable to backspace existing value of an input field in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmDa4.png)

I am using formik and yup.

Comment: you need to provide some code bro

Comment: usually in this type of case what happen is you input's value and onChange's e.target.value is not in sync properly.. but that I can say after looking into code only.